# How to check the multiple number of checkboxes?

Tags: checkbox, selenium-webdriver, checkboxlist, pageobjects

In My application, there are 24 checkboxes.

Do I need to find out all the page objects for 24 objects?

> **EDIT** Below is the HTML :

```html
<td>Gender</td>
<td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-check text-success" />
</td>
<td class="text-center">
  <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-checked="permission.friendGender" ng-model="permission.friendGender" />
</td>
<td class="text-center">
  <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-checked="permission.anyoneGender" ng-model="permission.anyoneGender" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not privileged to comment on question directly, hence posting a possible solution.
I am not sure how your check boxes are structured in HTML. But if your checkbox is with single unique ID having 24 different options, then you can do something similar to :

```
List<WebElement> CHECKBOXlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type='checkbox']"));
for(WebElement checkbox : CHECKBOXlist)

  {
     //do something with each checkbox.
     System.out.println(checkbox.getText());
     checkbox.click();
 }
```

Here you are literally getting all checkboxes with `driver.findElements()` instead of `driver.findElement()` (in your case, those 24 check boxes)

Comment: I have edited the question with HTML you gave. You may want to delete the HTML comment. Also it seems checkboxes neither have id nor name. So very few options remain to find out the element. 1. Use xPath locator if the number of checkboxes are constant. 2. Use cssSelector like I have used in my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for your info, do i need to specify all the objects in page objects ?

Comment: If you use Xpath to identify 24 checkboxes, yes need to specify all objects. If you use List by using cssSelector, then the List will have all the 24 checkboxes. I would suggest use cssSelector.

Comment: I executed using css selector but it's showing exception

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 20.18 seconds

Comment: i wrote like this

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.hidden-xs.ng-binding")).click();
  
     driver.findElement(By.linkText("Your Profile")).click();
  
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/button[2]")).click();
  
  List<WebElement> CHECKBOXlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid"));
  for(WebElement checkbox : CHECKBOXlist)

    {
       //do something with each checkbox.
       System.out.println(checkbox.getText());
       checkbox.click();
   }

Comment: No. You need to write as `List<WebElement> CHECKBOXlist = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[class='.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid ']"));` OR use `By.className(".ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid")`

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This is also not working, actually it's not showing any error or exception but checkboxes are not checking

Comment: if(profile.lbl_userName.isDisplayed() & profile.lbl_Email.isDisplayed() & profile.lbl_MyWeight.isDisplayed() & profile.lbl_Gender.isDisplayed() & profile.lbl_Height.isDisplayed() & profile.lbl_BirthDay.isDisplayed() & profile.lbl_JoinedDate.isDisplayed())
 {
 System.out.println("Labels of Username, Email, MyWeight, Gender, Height, Birthday and Joined date are displayed");
 }
Hi mk08, Can i use this code for validating the Labels ?

Comment: You may want to use `WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOut);   
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));` to avoid ElementNotVisibleException

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply. I tried with it, again it shows, org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 20.13 seconds

Comment: Well that is strange. I just now created HTML file from above code and wrote the same line of code as I suggested in Answer. It is very well executing successfully. Only I put `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` instead of wait for visiblity of element.

Comment: But for me it's not executing, Here in action class i wrote like this

Comment: public static void ClickOn_Importbtn(WebDriver driver)throws InterruptedException{
    InviteFriends_Page.Friends_InviteFriendsThroughGoogle importbtn=new InviteFriends_Page(). new Friends_InviteFriendsThroughGoogle(driver);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   importbtn.btn_ImportGmailCont.click();
   
   }

Comment: This is my page objects code
public class Friends_InviteFriendsThroughGoogle {
 
 public Friends_InviteFriendsThroughGoogle (WebDriver driver){
  PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
 }

// Invite friends page objects
     
     @FindBy(name="importbutton")
     public WebElement btn_ImportGmailCont;
}
}

Comment: Please don't post large bits of code in comments. It makes them really hard to read. If it's important to the question being answered, please post the code fragments inside the question where more people can see them and it can be properly formatted. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion JeffC. I'm new to this site.